# EOFError on hacker rank. Python 3

Tags: python

I have started to practice on HackerRank and I notice input() does not work. Below is an example code of the problem

```
   #!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys




def fizzBuzz(n):
    i =0
    while i < n:
        i = i +1
        if i%3 == 0 and i%5== 0:
            print("FizzBuzz")
        elif i%3==0 and i%5!=5:
            print("Fizz")
        elif i%3!=0 and i%5==0:
            print("Buzz")
        else:
            print(i)
    # Write your code here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n=int(input())
    fizzBuzz(n)
```

The function input() should be taking in a string input of 1< n < 2000. The code runs on IDLE, Pycharm, jupyter and even in a cmd line environment. However, when run against test case on HackerRank the following error is returned

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 33, in <module>
    n = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Please advise. Thank you

[image]

Comment: This will be one issue: `fizzBuzz(in)`. Change the variable to `n`.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the typo on my end. The problem still persist even when changed to n. I have added a SS of the error

Comment: Please send me the link to the problem in HackerRank so that I can read the question and figure out the exact issue as I don't see any mistakes in the program you have shown

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fizzbuzz/problem?h_r=internal-search here you go!

Comment: The `i%5!=5` and `i%3!=0` in elif statements are redundant. Also `i%5!=5` doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Aside: None of the imports are required for this code.

Answer (score 0):

Fix by using the Try and Except EOFerror issue. Still dont undestand why the issues of EOFerror in the first place

Comment: I wonder if HackerRank is looking for the functional code, and not a script?  In other words, their algorithm might not be expecting the `if __name__ == '__main__'` bit(?)